# Firebase Remote Config Fetch failed with user not authorized

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm trying to set up my production application to use remote config, but I'm getting a FirebaseRemoteConfigFetchException. This project is already deployed, we use FCM, Crashlytics and Dynamic Links. If I use the dev project on firebase everything work just fine. So I don't think it's the google-service.json configuration. The only difference between the configurations is in the production instance I have the SHA certificate fingerprint setup.

> 2019-02-08 22:59:52.755 19724-19744/? W/System.err:
>   java.io.IOException:
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzas.read()
>   returned value out of range -1..255: -117 2019-02-08 22:59:52.755
>   19724-19744/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte(GZIPInputStream.java:273)
>   2019-02-08 22:59:52.755 19724-19744/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUShort(GZIPInputStream.java:260)
>   2019-02-08 22:59:52.755 19724-19744/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:165)
>   2019-02-08 22:59:52.755 19724-19744/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.(GZIPInputStream.java:80)
>   2019-02-08 22:59:52.755 19724-19744/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.(GZIPInputStream.java:92)
>   2019-02-08 22:59:52.756 19724-19744/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzad.getContent(Unknown
>   Source:46) 2019-02-08 22:59:52.756 19724-19744/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzd.zza(Unknown
>   Source:12) 2019-02-08 22:59:52.756 19724-19744/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzm.zza(Unknown
>   Source:14) 2019-02-08 22:59:52.756 19724-19744/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzg.zzb(Unknown
>   Source:5) 2019-02-08 22:59:52.756 19724-19744/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzaa.zzad(Unknown
>   Source:178) 2019-02-08 22:59:52.756 19724-19744/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzf.zzi(Unknown
>   Source:51) 2019-02-08 22:59:52.757 19724-19744/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzer.zzc(Unknown
>   Source:41) 2019-02-08 22:59:52.757 19724-19744/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzer.zzb(Unknown
>   Source:23) 2019-02-08 22:59:52.757 19724-19744/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzer.zza(Unknown
>   Source:149) 2019-02-08 22:59:52.757 19724-19744/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzes.then(Unknown
>   Source:6) 2019-02-08 22:59:52.757 19724-19744/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source:2) 2019-02-08
>   22:59:52.757 19724-19744/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>   2019-02-08 22:59:52.757 19724-19744/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>   2019-02-08 22:59:52.757 19724-19744/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 2019-02-08 22:59:52.757
>   19724-19744/? E/FirebaseRemoteConfig: Fetch failed! Server responded
>   with an error.
>       com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzd: 403 Forbidden
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzm.zza(Unknown
>   Source:14)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzg.zzb(Unknown
>   Source:5)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzaa.zzad(Unknown
>   Source:178)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzf.zzi(Unknown
>   Source:51)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzer.zzc(Unknown
>   Source:41)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzer.zzb(Unknown
>   Source:23)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzer.zza(Unknown
>   Source:149)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzes.then(Unknown
>   Source:6)
>           at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source:2)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 2019-02-08 22:59:52.759 19724-19754/? E/FirebaseRemoteConfig: Fetch failed!
>       com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfigFetchException:
>   Fetch failed: The user is not authorized to access the project. Please
>   make sure you are using the API key that corresponds to your Firebase
>   project.
>       Check logs for details.
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzer.zzc(Unknown
>   Source:77)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzer.zzb(Unknown
>   Source:23)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzer.zza(Unknown
>   Source:149)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzes.then(Unknown
>   Source:6)
>           at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source:2)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Comment: @Swati I already downloaded the google-services.json file again just to make sure. Also just to make sure, I uploaded the app to the internal track of play store so the signing key is also correct

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After digging a little bit, and looking all over the place, I found that for some reason I had to go to https://console.developers.google.com -> Enable API and Services -> Firebase Remote Config, and enable that API. After doing that everything started to work again.

I hope this helps someone in the future, cheers!

Comment: I ran into the similar problem. Any idea why this is suddenly required? I don't think firebase docs ever mention this.

Comment: @rpattabi I'm not sure if it's your case, but digging I found this in their release notes 
"Remote Config version 16.3.0
The Firebase Remote Config SDK requires the Firebase Remote Config REST API. For Firebase projects created before March 7, 2018, you must manually enable the REST API. For more information, see our Remote Config REST API user guide." 
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: Thanks a ton. Somehow I had missed this completely. I don't remember firebase giving us a heads up on this.

Comment: I confirm that this is automatically enabled for my newer projects (as you mentioned).

Comment: You'll get the same error if your API_KEY from credentials keys at Google Cloud Console would has restrictions and doesn't have access for Firebase Remote Config API

Comment: @AshishSaini Enabling the API may not be enough. You may also need to allow the user to Google Cloud user to use the Remote API.

Comment: Here is the  link for release 16.3.0: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#version_1630

Comment: After enabling the API on the console I'm still getting reports of that issue. About 20% less than before, but still about 600 instances a day of that exception. Not sure why.
`Fetch failed: The user is not authorized to access the project. Please make sure you are using the API key that corresponds to your Firebase project.`

Answer (score 11):

I faced a similar issue in my Flutter project (it includes Android and iOS). On Android everything works fine (don't forget to add your debug SHA-1 in firebase settings) but on iOS I got the following error messages:

```
Runner[630:137105] 6.22.0 - [Firebase/RemoteConfig][I-RCN000026] RCN Fetch failure. Response http error code: 403

Runner[630:137105] 6.22.0 - [Firebase/Performance][I-PRF710001] Unable to fetch configurations.
```

Accepted answer by @eslimaf is correct but if Remote Config is already enabled you should try the comment by @cosic, it saved my day.

For those who struggle to find where to change those restrictions I'll add a few screenshots.
All credits to @cosic

1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com
2. Open Credentials tab, open Android or iOS key in API Keys section
   [image]
3. Check "Don't restrict key" or if you check "Restrict key" - make sure you've added all your services that you need.
   [image]
4. Click SAVE, changes will take effect in a couple of minutes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I wished this answer and the accepted answer were merged. Life saver indeed.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, to isolate a Remote Config issue, I had created a second app in the same Firebase project. I ran into this same issue. (I'm using flutter, but this would likely apply to Android, iOS...)

When I created the second app, it also created a second (unrestricted) API key. However, the newly-downloaded `google-services.json` lists both keys for my second (testing) app.

```
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "<this is the key for the original app>"
        },
        {
          "current_key": "this is the key auto created for the Testing app"
        }
      ],
```

There doesn't seem to be a way, at least in the console, to specify which API key should be used for each app. (UPDATE - See #4 in resolution below) So `google-services.json` appears to be project-wide and contains every client, with every API key. The first key was used, which is for the non-testing app, and was more locked down. Thus causing this issue.

**Resolution**

Remove the `api_key` from that is incorrect for the app from `google-services.json`, since it will select the first one. Or see #4 below

**How to diagnose this issue**

1. Print out the Firebase options to get active api_key

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    // options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform, <- Uncomment this if using generated firebase_options.dart
  );
  print(Firebase.apps[0].options.toString() + "\n");
```

result: `I/flutter (22314): {apiKey: some-api-key, appId: 1:some-app-id ...`

2. Search workspace to see where key is provided, probably in `google-services.json`
3. If you know this is incorrect and want to force other key, remove incorrect key and clean, rebuild. To Fix correctly, see next step.
4. Per [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys#faq-auto-matching-app-to-key) the `google-services.json` associates the app with the key via the bundle Id, **which isn't set by default**. Find the key in Cloud console (not Firebase console) in API -> Credentials. Set the restrictions on the key to Android (for example) with bundleId and sha.

**Link contents for prosperity!**

```
"How does Firebase know which API key to match to an app (like in the Firebase config file/object)?

When you first obtain your app's Firebase config file/object, Firebase checks if there are any existing API keys in your project that have "Application Restrictions" that match the app (for example, a matching bundle ID for the Apple app).

If Firebase doesn't find any restricted keys that match, then it will list in the config file/object the iOS key for Apple apps, the Android key for Android apps, and the Browser key for web apps (assuming that these keys exist and have no "Application Restrictions" that keep them from matching to that app)."
```