# FirebaseRemoteConfigClientException on production (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

**What have I done so far...**

I am using `Tasks.await` [blocking](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks#blocking) mechanism for firebase calls in worker threads for avoiding callbacks.

I am using a worker thread (JobIntentService) for some initialization progress. JobIntentService starts when app opens and runs only once. below is my worker thread code

```
    if (isDeviceConnectedToInternet()) {
        Tasks.await(FirebaseConfigHelper.getRemoteConfig().fetchAndActivate()); //error here
        initFirebaseConfigVariables();
        // other codes
    }

//FirebaseConfigHelper.java
public static FirebaseRemoteConfig getRemoteConfig() {
    FirebaseRemoteConfig mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaultsAsync(R.xml.remote_config_defaults);
    return mFirebaseRemoteConfig;
}
```

I am using

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.0.4'
```

**About the error**

It is working fine in testing devices. I tested in another 15 Devices in [Firebase Test Lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab). There was no issues at all. but when I released to production this error occurred in some specific Mi and Samsung devices.

**Error log**

I was able to get only this log, because error happens in production

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfigClientException:
The client had an error while calling the backend!  at
com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zzb(Unknown Source:61)   at
com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(Unknown Source:23) at
com.maju.myapp.service.SyncWithFirebaseJobIntentService.syncWithFirebaseConfig(SyncWithFirebaseJobIntentService.java:207)   at
com.maju.myapp.service.SyncWithFirebaseJobIntentService.onHandleWork(SyncWithFirebaseJobIntentService.java:55)  at
androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:392)   at
androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:383)   at
android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378) at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)Caused by:
com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfigClientException:
The client had an error while calling the backend!  at
com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.internal.ConfigFetchHttpClient.fetch(com.google.firebase:firebase-config@@19.0.4:194)  at
com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.internal.ConfigFetchHandler.fetchFromBackend(com.google.firebase:firebase-config@@19.0.4:278)  at
com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.internal.ConfigFetchHandler.fetchFromBackendAndCacheResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-config@@19.0.4:251)  at
com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.internal.ConfigFetchHandler.fetchIfCacheExpiredAndNotThrottled(com.google.firebase:firebase-config@@19.0.4:191)    at
com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.internal.ConfigFetchHandler.lambda$fetch$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-config@@19.0.4:160)    at
com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.internal.ConfigFetchHandler$$Lambda$1.then(Unknown
Source:4)   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown
Source:2)   ... 3 moreCaused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to
connect to
firebaseremoteconfig.googleapis.com/2404:6800:4007:809::200a:443    at
com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:147)    at
com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)  at
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186) at
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)  at
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)   at
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)    at
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)    at
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)   at
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)   at
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:262)   at
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:219) at
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)  at
com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.internal.ConfigFetchHttpClient.setFetchRequestBody(com.google.firebase:firebase-config@@19.0.4:321)    at
com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.internal.ConfigFetchHttpClient.fetch(com.google.firebase:firebase-config@@19.0.4:182)  ...
9 more
```

1. Why this is happening?
2. How to avoid it?

(Callbacks are making code ugly and messy, for making clean code I prefer Tasks.await)

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54603795/1318946

Comment: @PratikButani It was already enabled

Comment: Possibly bad Internet connection?

Comment: @TashPemhiwa may be, but I checked Device Connected To Internet before calling firebase config fetch

Comment: It might speak to the quality of the Internet connection versus not having a connection at all.

Comment: You are right @TashPemhiwa. Thank u

Comment: Glad to have been of service!

Comment: @majurageerthan Any changes you made that made this error go away?

Comment: @hemanthkumar I checked network connectivity before calling firebase config to avoid this issue... In case user has network issues, show a pop up with network issues. It reduced the issue, but not completely mitigated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I contacted Firebase Support for this issue**

They said

> This happens if the connection of the device user had an issue as our
>   SDK tried to call the fetch of data, and it would cause “**The client
>   had an error while calling the backend!**” error. With that, it looks
>   like you’re doing the right thing on validating the connectivity on
>   your recent updates before you fetch the remote config data. You can
>   check our implementation [here](https://cs.opensource.google/firebase-sdk/firebase-android-sdk/+/master:firebase-config/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/internal/ConfigFetchHttpClient.java;drc=cfaeae14af2c457c3fb07da4f217f33d45b48a1a;l=196) that you could visualize our call
>   that would trigger this issue.
>
> You could use the [Android network debugger](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/network-profiler) to simulate the
>   network calls, so you could catch your handling mechanism to ensure
>   that your actual device has a proper connectivity on doing the fetch.

So the problem might be the network connectivity of the device. I check the network connectivity in recent updates. but still I am getting this error in some devices. The reason may be the the poor quality of the Internet connection at the moment of the devices (@Tash Pemhiwa suggested in comment)

Answer (score 1):

An API that makes an app crash, with no option to catch the exception, when a device is offline or the connection drops while accessing it. Amazing. But interestingly, using `addOnCompleteListener` instead of `await` works fine.

Hence there's a solution, add and use this helper instead:

```
suspend fun fetchAndActivateRemoteConfig() = suspendCancellableCoroutine {
    Firebase.remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate().addOnCompleteListener { _ ->
        it.resume(Unit)
    }
}
```

It's important that you do not try to access the result of `addOnCompleteListener`, because doing so may trigger yet another crash that Google really does not want to fix: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/5540

```
Fatal Exception: com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfigClientException: Firebase Installations failed to get installation auth token for fetch.
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.getResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:3)
```

If you do require the true/false result, you'll need to resort to manually checking `Firebase.remoteConfig.info.lastFetchStatus` after this call, which doesn't seem to crash.

Comment: Wow. that worked. I was trying to print a result of adOnCompleteListener which was causing crash. Removing it fixed. I was so frustrated. thanks.