# How to investigate errors in Firebase Remote Config API?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-remote-config

I see errors for the Firebase Remote Config API in the *Google Cloud Console > API/Service Details* metrics.

Looking at "Traffic by response code" I see that a specific API key is causing HTTP code 400 responses from the API for the method:

`google.firebase.remoteconfig.v1.RemoteConfigService.FetchRemoteConfig`

I'm not able to reproduce this issue locally so how can I find out more about these errors in the Google Cloud Console?

What I've checked so far:

- The credential that is causing the errors is restricted to the correct package name and SHA-1 hash (hash taken from Google Play Console > App Integrity)
- It's apparently not hitting a quota limit from looking at the quote graph

From the client side logs I only see the exception:

> com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.g: The client had an error while calling the backend!

Comment: Does this [GitHub link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3333) addresses your issue?

Comment: I don't think so, the issue occurs for me on a variety of Android versions, from v4 to v12. Also, it all works locally, the issue only occurs in the published app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Developer Support pointed me to a known [bug](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3757) in the Firebase Remote Config library which has been fixed recently. Upgrading the library indeed fixed the issue.

Comment: 1 year after this answer, using the latest version currently `21.4.0` and the issue persists like a charm! I don't belive they fixed any thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard error message used in the Remote Config SDK for a client error (ex: a connection timeout, SSL issue, etc.). I suggest that you double check your implementation. You could also use the [Android network debugger](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/network-profiler) to simulate the network calls, so it could create a handling mechanism to ensure that the actual device has a proper connectivity on doing the fetch.

You may also refer to the [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60595972/firebaseremoteconfigclientexception-on-production-android) and the [GitHub Link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1515).